# Passing entire select statement as a parameter - PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Im passing an entire select statement as a parameter to a Postgres function like below...

```
select * from demo_spnsearch('select* from public.tbl_spnsearch where spnid=78 and spnyear=2000::varchar and region=Australia')
```

I get an error

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "australia" does not exist   Where:
> PL/pgSQL function demo_spnsearch(text) line 6 at RETURN QUERY

But when i pass the same  without region

```
select * from demo_spnsearch('select* from public.tbl_spnsearch where spnid=78 and spnyear=2000::varchar ')
```

it works fine.

Please help...

Comment: Put it in quotes `region=''Australia''` // `select * from demo_spnsearch('select* from public.tbl_spnsearch where spnid=78 and spnyear=2000::varchar and region=''Australia'')` . why are you using the entire select statement as param when you can easily handle the select statements inside a function just by passing the `region` and other columns as param?. I would say, what you are doing is a wrong approach

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but again i get an error like below

Comment: SQL Error [42601]: Unterminated string literal started at position 90 in SQL select * from demo_spnsearch('select* from public.tbl_spnsearch where  region=''Australia''). Expected  char

Comment: Check the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `region` value inside the quotes. You may use any of the below options

```
SELECT *
FROM demo_spnsearch('select* from public.tbl_spnsearch where spnid=78 and spnyear=2000::varchar and region=''Australia''') -- note the quotes here region=''Australia''
```

By using Postgres inbuilt [format()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function.

```
SELECT *
FROM  demo_spnsearch(format('select* from public.tbl_spnsearch where spnid=%s and spnyear=%s::varchar and region=%L', 78, 2000, 'Australia'))
```